# Objective-C in,out,inout,byref,byval, .. and so on. What are they?

Tags: objective-c

I discovered something unfamiliar while reading Objective-C manual for `@encoding`.

```
Table 6-2  Objective-C method encodings
Code Meaning
r    const
n    in
N    inout
o    out
O    bycopy
R    byref
V    oneway
```

The only thing I know is `oneway`. What are the others?

Answer (score 88, accepted):

Those are annotations for method parameters and return values which were used by Distributed Objects. I say *were* because apparently there’s no sign of them in Apple’s documentation any longer. There used to be a Remote Messaging section in The Objective-C Programming Language document, which is still referenced by the Distributed Objects Programming Topics document.

- **in:** argument is an input argument only and won’t be referenced later
- **out:** argument is an output argument only, used to return a value by reference
- **inout:** argument is both an input and output argument
- **const:** the (pointer) argument is constant
- **bycopy:** instead of using a proxy/`NSDistantObject`, pass or return a copy of the object
- **byref:** use a proxy object (default)

Comment: Thanks a lot! Especially, the documentation is no more available. In fact, I have been looked for the documentation but all links were broken.

Comment: FWIW, Apple used `inout` in the new `UIScrollViewDelegate` method. (`targetContentOffset:(inout CGPoint *)targetContentOffset`. That's way I came here, anyways.

Comment: Actually me too. If they can use inout, why the hell they need to do something complicated like doing double pointer to get error? Actually given that they pass CGPOINT * they do not need to specify inout at all. It's a pointer. CGPOINT is a struct. As long as you put the new CGPOINT to the address pointed by targetContentOffset, you'll do fine.

Comment: More references in NSDateFormatter.h

Comment: apple uses inout,out in validation valus for keys.   -(BOOL)validateValue:(inout __autoreleasing id *)ioValue forKey:(NSString *)inKey error:(out NSError *__autoreleasing *)outError

Comment: `inout` is also used `UIPopoverViewController`: `-popoverController:willRepositionPopoverToRect:inView:`

Comment: @AnonymousWhite There is nothing special about `inout` - it is simply an informational directive to other programmers. It can only be used in protocols. It cannot replace parameters of type `NSError **error` and the like: in fact, in this case the parameter in question (`CGPoint *`) used in exactly the same way.

Answer (score 27):

Beyond Distributed Objects, one of these annotations appears to be used by ARC. I came across the following in clang's description of [passing to an out parameter by writeback](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html#passing-to-an-out-parameter-by-writeback):

> If the parameter is not an Objective-C method parameter marked `out`, then `*p` is read, and the result is written into the temporary with primitive semantics.

This has to do with methods like `- (BOOL)executeWithError:(out NSError **)error`.

Ignoring the `out` keyword, ARC has a [well-defined behavior of treating by-reference object passing as `__autoreleasing`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/releasenotes/ObjectiveC/RN-TransitioningToARC/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011226-CH1-SW4), so ARC treats the `error` parameter as having a type of `NSError * __autoreleasing *`.  If you use an otherwise qualified variable, ARC will add a temporary autoreleasing variable pass into the function (for coherence):

**Original code**

```
NSError *error;
[obj executeWithError:&error];
```

**Pseudotransformed code**

```
NSError * __strong error;
NSError * __autoreleasing temp;
temp = error;
[obj executeWithError:&temp];
error = temp;
```

With the above code, the line `temp = error` would be unnecessary if we could somehow know that `temp` will never be read.  This is where the `out` annotation comes into play.  Per the quoted description if `out` is missing the compiler must add the line `temp = error` but if it does contain `out` it can exclude the line and make the code just a little bit smaller/faster.  With `out` the transformed code becomes:

```
NSError * __strong error;
NSError * __autoreleasing temp;
[obj executeWithError:&temp];
error = temp;
```

*Of course, if you're that worried about binary size and speed, you should just code the following:*

```
NSError * __autoreleasing error;
[obj executeWithError:&error];
```

It is entirely possible that these annotations are used other places throughout the compiler and runtime, and may be used in more places in the future.  Personally, I like using `out` as a hint to other developers that I'm not going to read the value.

Comment: *Original Code* seems lacking one address-of operator. `executeWithError:&error];`

Comment: @BrianNickel so (out NSError **) and (NSError * __autoreleasing *) are the same ?

Comment: @denis631 No. `(out NSError **)` is the same as `(out NSError * __autoreleasing *)` and `(NSError **)` is the same type as `(NSError * __autoreleasing *)`.  The injection of `__autoreleasing` is part of ARC's design, similar to how all variables are `__strong` unless specified.  `out` isn't part of the type but an annotation that the compiler can use to optimize.

Comment: @BrianNickel so what does "out" keyword do? It only removes this line of code: temp = error; Or it does something more ?

Comment: It just removes that one line.  I'll update the answer to clarify.

Comment: @BrianNickel what does "out" keyword does in general. When would I possibly use it (other than distributed objects, which I haven't learned yet)

Comment: @BrianNickel what do you mean by saying: "if we could somehow know that temp will never be read. This is where the out annotation comes into play." If the code with "out" is faster, why almost nobody is using it ?

Comment: @denis631 it's optional, obscure, and such a minor savings in the grand scheme of things that pretty much no one should ever need it.

Comment: I believe that the `out` keyword is crucial if one is using the objective-C bridgesupport metadata parser. In particular, I know that `pyobjc` treats out parameters specially and without such designation any particular API with an out parameter can not be used out of the box without manually adding the notation to the method call at runtime.

Comment: @denis631 It tells compiler to assume that current value of the object pointer passed as `out` is of no importance and can be ignored. However, if you search for `OBJC_TQ_Out` in clang's source code you'll find that its only use is to elide an assignment Brian referred to. Very little gain.

Answer (score 0):

Incase anyone has stumbled across this post and has the same confusion as me, the 'in' argument can also be a keyword that represents fast enumeration. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9003160/objective-c-keyword-in) for more details.

Comment: Such a common construct in other current languages, like Java and Python, but virtually never used in Obj-C. Personally, I tend to use blockEnumerators when I need this sort of thing even though it involves a lot more typing... IDK, I feel anyone reading my code is more likely to instantly get it that way.

Answer (score -3):

You can read the Objective-C runtime sources http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/objc4/objc4-437.1/ to understand what these annotations mean.