# Objective C Keyword 'in'

Tags: objective-c

Im having some problems understanding some code in a programme I have inherited.

```
CGPoint tapLocation = [gesture locationInView:self.view];
for (UIView *view in self.view.subviews){
    if (!CGRectContainsPoint(view.frame, tapLocation)){
        //do something
    }
}
```

The problem is that I have no idea what the keyword 'in' is doing. I've searched around and can only find some obscure reference to it and a [post here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5609564/objective-c-in-out-inout-byref-byval-and-so-on-what-are-they).

The post says that:

```
in: argument is an input argument only and won’t be referenced later
```

I don't really see how  this applies to the code above. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "in" you're seeing there is part of Fast Enumeration.

[Here is some documentation for it.](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/watchos/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/FoundationTypesandCollections/FoundationTypesandCollections.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011210-CH7-SW30)

***EDIT***: And Derek pointed out another bit of documentation in his comment below.

Comment: Looks like the link is no longer active. I've found the Mac Cocoa Core Competencies documentation which looks to be the most relevant currently: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/General/Conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/Enumeration.html Their explanation of Fast Enumeration: "Fast Enumeration - Several Cocoa classes, including the collection classes, adopt the NSFastEnumeration protocol. You use it to retrieve elements held by an instance using a syntax similar to that of a standard C for loop"

Answer (score 3):

I think apple calls this [fast enumeration](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/objectivec/Chapters/ocFastEnumeration.html).

In other languages a similar functionality is provided by a "for each"-loop.

Comment: wow that's awesome! Thanks! Ive been looking for an answer for ages! This is my first post on stack overflow - can't believe how quick an answer came.

Comment: yeah... 7 answers, almost completely the same.

Comment: I know! They were coming in quicker than I could write a comment. Thanks to everyone for the answers.

Comment: I almost don't believe you when you say that you couldn't find it, but I guess it's possible. People answer easy questions fast (and with the same answers usually), which is kind of a waste.

Comment: Its not really a waste. If you don't know that 'in' is related to fast enumeration, how would you search for it. Googling 'for loop with in' is hardly very helpful. I went down the line of finding definitions of keywords, and thats how i came to the post I mentioned. At least this post explains it for others who may find themselves confused by objective c and its use of 'in'.

Comment: Googling "objective c for loop in" (without the quotes) returns the answer in the top two results. Anyway, you're right. Waste is the wrong word for it since it will probably help someone.

Answer (score 1):

It's a succinct way to iterate through a collection. Where it says:

```
for (object in collection)
```

it means "this code happens once for each object in the collection".

Answer (score 1):

The ***in*** in the link you've specified in your question is entirely different from the ***in*** in the *for* loop. The farmer comes under ***@encoding*** and the later comes in the context of *for* loops. This kind of *for* loop is called ***for-each*** loop in general, and in Objective-C it is called ***fast enumeration***.

Answer (score 0):

It creates an enumerator automatically for you such that you can iterator over the collection. So the collection has to conform to NSFastEnumeration.

Answer (score 0):

`in` is used to iterete through an array.

For instance:

```
    NSArray *values = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"val1", @"val2", @"val3", nil];
    for (NSString *val in values) {
            NSLog(@"Value = '%@'", val);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically, this is an extension of the for loop built for objective-c. 
Think of this code like this:

```
for (NSArray *arr = UIViewGetSubviews(UIViewControllerGetView(self)), i = 0; i < arr.count; i++)  {
}
```

Note that the actual implementation uses a `NSEnumerator`, not a for with integer variable loop.

Comment: It doesn't use an NSEnumerator, it uses a realisation of NSFastEnumeration. There's a huge difference in implementation and performance between those two.