# What does inout CGPoint * mean as a parameter?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview, uiscrollviewdelegate

In the UIScrollView delegate methods, there's:

`scrollViewWillEndDragging:withVelocity:targetContentOffset:`

and the last parameter is:

`(inout CGPoint *)targetContentOffset`

I'm curious as to what the inout means and why CGPoint is a pointer. I tried printing targetContentOffset to the console, but I'm not sure how to do so as well. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: For printing, use `*targetContentOffset` to fetch the thing it points to, or `targetContentOffset->x` (`->` instead of `.`) to access members of a struct via pointer; I'm sure someone will give a properly substantial answer as to the whys.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

It means the parameter is used to send data `in` but also to get data `out`.

Let's see an example implementation:

```
- (void)increment:(inout NSUInteger*)number {
    *number = *number + 1;
}


NSUInteger someNumber = 10;
[self increment:&someNumber];
NSLog(@"Number: %u", someNumber); //prints 11
```

This pattern is often used with C structures, e.g `CGPoint` because they are passed by value (copied).

Also note that `inout` is not absolutely required there but it helps the compiler to understand the meaning of your code and do better job when optimizing.

There are also separate `in` and `out` annonations but as far as I know there are no compiler warnings when you misuse them and it doesn't seem Apple is using them any more.

Comment: Do you happen to know where in/out/inout etc are documented? They are still present in the preprocessed output, so it must be compiler keywords and not macros, but I could not find an official reference.

Comment: @MartinR Me neither. The were probably used only for distributed objects, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5609564/objective-c-in-out-inout-byref-byval-and-so-on-what-are-they