# What does id _Nullable __autoreleasing * _Nonnull mean?

Tags: objective-c, objective-c++, objective-c-nullability

I am confused with the usage of `(out id  _Nullable *)` in the code docs and the error my snippet throws at me.

```c
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

void getvalue(char *a, bool *value){
  @autoreleasepool {
    NSURL *url = [[NSURL alloc] initFileURLWithFileSystemRepresentation:a 
                                                            isDirectory:NO 
                                                          relativeToURL:nil];
    [url getResourceValue:value 
                   forKey:NSURLIsDirectoryKey 
                    error:nil];
  }
}

void main (int argc, const char * argv[])
{
  bool value[10];
  char a[] = "a";
  getvalue(a, value + 4);
}
```

> Cannot initialize a parameter of type 'id  _Nullable __autoreleasing * _Nonnull' with an lvalue of type 'bool *'

What does `_Nullable * _Nonnull` mean and what am I doing wrong in the code?

Reference:

[`getResourceValue:forKey:error:`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsurl/1408874-getresourcevalue?language=objc)

```c
- (BOOL)getResourceValue:(out id  _Nullable *)value 
                  forKey:(NSURLResourceKey)key 
                   error:(out NSError * _Nullable *)error;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`_Nullable * _Nonnull` isn't the issue here. The problem is you're passing a pointer to a bool when you need to pass a pointer to a pointer to an object. `getResourceValue:forKey:error:` returns an object, not a primitive. In this case, an [NSNumber](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsurlisdirectorykey?language=objc#).

```
    NSNumber *result = nil;
    [url getResourceValue:&result
                   forKey:NSURLIsDirectoryKey
                    error:nil];
    *value = [result boolValue];
```

To the question, `id _Nullable * _Nonnull` means "a pointer, which must not be null, to an object-pointer, which may be null." This is the standard return-by-reference pattern in ObjC. `id` is a typedef for a pointer-to-an-object.

Comment: Glad to have it verified! I also did the same thing (it's been 6 hours, I could figure it out). thanks! Please add a bit about `out id`, I am not sure about it. How do you know it is an NSNumber ?

Comment: I've never actually seen `out` before. I suspect it's a new annotation to improve bridging to Swift's exclusive-ownership model. I don't believe it has semantic meaning in ObjC (though perhaps the optimizer can make use of it). I know this returns an NSNumber because the docs tell us so: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsurlisdirectorykey?language=objc#

Comment: @ankii Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5609870/2229783) for more details about `out`.